# how to trigger search button on tab is opened(Clicked)?

Tags: views

I have two views to display search result for user list and content list respectively using exposed filter. I have shown shown both views as a tab (Content and Users) on a page with exposed filter separate for each. When I search for content with filter criteria it displays list of contents. Now what I want to do is when I click on User tab it should display results for users with same filter criteria. Is there anybody who already has done this functionality?   Hope the image will help you to understand my question.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered making content / user just another exposed filter and only styling them as tabs? Just an idea...

Comment: Can you please share your Views exported code?

Comment: Views exported code is too big.